# Aren't bus voltage angles directly measurable?

Tags: voltage-measurement, steady-state

> The state of the AC power system is expressed by the voltage magnitudes and phase angles at the buses. Although **relative phase angles of bus voltages cannot be measured**, they can be calculated using real-time data acquired from the system

(From *Power Systems Analysis* by Grainger/Stevenson, p664).

The claim in bold is provided without justification. Why can the relative phase angles of bus voltages not be measured directly?

Comment: That book looks to be almost 30 years old. It may be that we can measure things more directly now. If I wanted to measure phase angles in a circuit, I would use an oscilloscope, but you can't hook an oscilloscope directly to an AC power system of the kind they're probably talking about (high voltage); it wouldn't be safe, for the scope or the operator. It does seem like you should be able to do it with current transformers and a scope easily enough, though.

Comment: Later in the book it says "The phase angles of the voltages at different substations of the system cannot be **economically** measured, but voltage magnitudes are routinely monitored" - which is a kind of justification.

Comment: To determine the  relative phase angles of a three phase bus, you need the zero crossing time for all three phases. The phase angle is the quotient of a phase shift between two phases and the period time. So the angles are calculated from some measurements but not measured directly.

Comment: Frequency is known to be identical. *Assuming* same amplitude sine waves, any pair of voltages allows exactly two angle differences, unless both are at peak.

Comment: Bruce thank you for that pointer. Glenn good point about the book's age... I'm trying to mitigate the risk of outdated text by referring to both this and a more recent edition of the same book. In general, how much would you say power systems analysis has changed in the past three decades?

Answer (score 0):

Given that bus voltages and currents are routinely monitored or measured, there is barely any overhead involved in calculating phase angle differences (or power factor) from the voltages and currents measured. The math is, in most cases, a simple Pythagorean triangle calculation. Phase meters (which directly measure phase angle) are a rarer breed of instrument that just are not needed in the majority of cases.

Apart from anything else, trying to measure phase angles of current waveforms using zero-cross algorithms is fraught with error because of the sine wave distortions caused by non-linear loads.